# Proxy to create object of WCF class

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf

Pardon me for this naive question.
I have created a service reference of a WCF service at the client side, In the example I have they mentioned they have created a proxy to create an object of the WCF class, I want to understand where "ServiceCalculateCostClient" came from. Below is the client call -

```
        CalculateCost.IServiceCalculateCost ICost = new CalculateCost.ServiceCalculateCostClient();
        CalculateCost.ProductData objProductData = new CalculateCost.ProductData();
        objProductData.ProductName = "Shirts";
        objProductData.ProductQuantity = 4;
        objProductData.PerProductCost = 200;
        Response.Write(ICost.getTotalCost(objProductData));
```

And here is the SVC code

```
public class ServiceCalculateCost : IServiceCalculateCost
{
    string IServiceCalculateCost.getTotalCost(ProductData objProductData)
    {
        double totalCost = objProductData.PerProductCost * objProductData.ProductQuantity;
        return "The total cost for product " + objProductData.ProductName + " is " + totalCost.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: the ServiceCalculateCostClient was automatically created when you added a service reference to the WCF service. you can use the client object created to call the functions of the WCF service

Comment: Thanks a ton Sujit, I realised the Client proxy is created by the name of the of the interface, suffixed with the word client.